# how to use %timeit and put it in a variable like "a" with "-o"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, interactive

I want to use `%timeit` and put it in a variable like "a" with `-o` to show Code execution speed

I try this but it is not true
`%%timeit [-n<N> -r<R> [-t|-c] -q -p<P> -o]` statement
so where can I put my code?
and where can I put my variable to show it?
can you see me what should I do for this problem?

Comment: You can only use `%timeit` magic command in the IPython console, not the plain Python interpreter. Just do `pip install ipython` and call `ipython`.

Comment: Which tool did you use, jupyter-notebook or ipython?

Answer (score 1):

In an ipython session, the regular timeit shows the result:

```
In [186]: %%timeit
     ...: np.arange(100)
     ...: 
     ...: 
919 ns ± 9.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

With `-o` that result is returned in the next `Out`:

```
In [187]: %%timeit -o
     ...: np.arange(100)
     ...: 
     ...: 
919 ns ± 8.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
Out[187]: <TimeitResult : 919 ns ± 8.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)>
```

That's accessible by name `Out[187]` or as last result `_`, and can be stored in anther variable:

```
In [188]: a=_
In [189]: a
Out[189]: <TimeitResult : 919 ns ± 8.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)>

In [193]: type(a)
Out[193]: IPython.core.magics.execution.TimeitResult
```

`-o` looks like a argparse True/False flag, so doesn't take an argument.  And we can't do `a = %%timeit -o`.  But quite often I use the `a=_` to "capture" the latest output - not just in case like this.

That result has various attributes (see `vars(a))

```
In [197]: a.all_runs
Out[197]: 
[0.9127235789783299,
 0.9326286749856081,
 0.9096248800051399,
 0.9201276109961327,
 0.9313049729971681,
 0.9111351100145839,
 0.9175998449791223]
In [198]: a.best
Out[198]: 9.096248800051399e-07
```

Note - this is the first time I explored this option (though I use `timeit` quite a bit for SO answers).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can't use %timeit with variables directly but you can use timeit module in python. Here an example for you:

```
import timeit

code_to_measure = '''
result = sum(range(1, 1000000))
'''

execution_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=code_to_measure, number=1)
print("Execution time:", execution_time)
```